# Using Synth, Gsynth or microsynth on IPUMS survey data

Tags: synthetic-controls

I am testing the impact of a policy in USA and I would like to use IPUMS data for all the states in the united states with 4 states experiencing the treatment in a particular year. I was thinking of converting the data into panel data structure by aggregating it by state by year to create the historical data but I just had the thought to just perform SCM on the micro data. Is there any advice or resource that anyone knows of that you think will be helpful for me? Please let me know. Thank you!